# Error in importing Google Sheets csv into BigQuery via Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery, google-sheets-api

I am trying to use the below Google Apps Script to import a Google Sheet from Sheets to BigQuery. The table is created with correct schema/location, but the data does not load into it. The error given is:

"CSV table references column position 1, but line starting at position:9 contains only 1 columns. (error code: invalid)"

Cells of columns A-E, rows 1-8 contain data and the rest is empty.

```
function loadCsv() {
// Replace this value with the project ID listed in the Google
// Cloud Platform project.
var projectId = 'xxxxxxx';

// Create a dataset in the BigQuery UI (https://bigquery.cloud.google.com)
// and enter its ID below.
var datasetId = 'zzzzzzzz';

// Sample CSV file of Google Trends data conforming to the schema below.
// https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwzA1Orbvy5WMXFLaTR1Z1p2UDg/edit
var csvFileId = 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyy';

// Create the table.
var tableId = 'new_' + new Date().getTime();

var table = {
tableReference: {
  projectId: projectId,
  datasetId: datasetId,
  tableId: tableId
},
schema: {
  fields: [
    {name: 'channelGrouping', type: 'STRING'},
    {name: 'medium', type: 'STRING'},
    {name: 'date', type: 'STRING'},
    {name: 'sessions', type: 'INTEGER'},
    {name: 'pageviews', type: 'INTEGER'}
   ]
  }
};
table = BigQuery.Tables.insert(table, projectId, datasetId);
Logger.log('Table created: %s', table.id);

// Load CSV data from Drive and convert to the correct format for upload.
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(csvFileId);
var data = file.getBlob().setContentType('application/octet-stream');

// Create the data upload job.
var job = {
 configuration: {
   load: {
     destinationTable: {
       projectId: projectId,
       datasetId: datasetId,
       tableId: tableId
    },
    skipLeadingRows: 1
  }
 }
 };
job = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, projectId, data);
Logger.log('Load job started. Check on the status of it here: ' +
   'https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/jobs/%s', projectId);
}
```

If anyone could give me a hint on why this may be the case, I would really appreciate it.
Thanks,

edit: The answer in the below thread has solved my problem. Basically, there is an issue in taking a GSheet as CSV, and this solution instead takes a range from the GSheet and makes that a CSV input.

[Google sheets upload to bigquery: Bad character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33931180/google-sheets-upload-to-bigquery-bad-character/33963410)

Comment: Can you show what your csv looks like?

Comment: Can you share it please? Thanks

Comment: Yes but it is not shared with anyone so I cannot see the contents

Comment: Sorry about that, this one should be accessible. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JAbKglEidvvGpuMkwd7aPpc2TOCfjAcZivynp0yGS6A/pubhtml

Comment: Thanks. Is that the file you are trying to upload or is it the csv data copied to a spreadsheet?

Comment: I currently do not have access to the actual GSheet but it is identical to this. The actual GSheet is a product of an Apps Script import from a Google Analytics account (as far as I can make out, all cells contained hard coded values.) I have tried the script above with both GSheet and csv uploaded to google drive as input, with no luck.